# xPath attribute value in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I try to get attrbiute and data from an XML with xPath.
I cant' get attribute.

XML:

```
<table:table-row>
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="Tabella1.A2" office:value-type="string">
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">RAG. SOC.:</text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="Tabella1.B2" office:value-type="string">
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
            <text:database-display text:table-name="portale.anaTanagrafica" text:table-type="table" text:column-name="ana_rag_sociale" text:database-name="Nuovo database">&lt;ana_rag_sociale&gt;</text:database-display>
        </text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
</table:table-row>
```

and PHP function:

```
$path = "//text:database-display";        
if ($xml !== FALSE) {
    foreach($xml->xpath($path) as $agenzia) {
        FB::INFO("Nodo: " . $agenzia);
        FB::INFO("Nodo: " . $agenzia[@"text:table-name"]);
    } 
}
```

What I want is the following output:

```
Nodo: &lt;ana_rag_sociale&gt;
Nodo: portale.anaTanagrafica
```

ThankS!!

Comment: please post the namespace-prefix of the XML as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the namespace with `SimpleXML`:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('text', 'youractualtextnamespace');
```

Once you've done that, there are a few ways to access the data you want. Here is a complete example:

```
$string = <<<XML
<table:table-row xmlns:table="youractualnamespace"
    xmlns:office="youractualofficenamespace" xmlns:text="youractualtextnamespace">
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="Tabella1.A2"
        office:value-type="string">
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">RAG. SOC.:</text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="Tabella1.B2"
        office:value-type="string">
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
            <text:database-display text:table-name="portale.anaTanagrafica"
                text:table-type="table" text:column-name="ana_rag_sociale"
                text:database-name="Nuovo database">&lt;ana_rag_sociale&gt;</text:database-display>
        </text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
</table:table-row>
XML;

$path = "//text:database-display";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('text', 'youractualtextnamespace');
if ($xml !== FALSE) {
    foreach($xml->xpath($path) as $agenzia) {
        $attr = $agenzia->xpath("@text:table-name");
        print("Nodo: " . $agenzia);
        print("Nodo: " . $attr[0]);
    }
}
```